# Other forms needed at the Auslanderbehorde for work visa in Germany?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, paperwork

I'm a US citizen applying for a work visa at the Auslanderbehorde in Berlin. Aside from the listed required forms (registered residence, passport, passport photos, residence permit application, job description form, permission for job application, job offer/contract, rental agreement, bank statement, proof of health insurance, and copies and copies and copies of some of these), are there any other forms I need? I keep reading in various blogs/accounts that people have been sent back because they're missing "some specific form" - but no one has said WHAT those forms are. What are some other forms/documents they might ask for? I've read about maybe needing a "certificate of good conduct" and a "certificate of good health" on older blogs, but the document requirements on my registration page say NOTHING about it. Do I need them? And other forms?

Comment: Usually you can email Auslanderbehorde and they should let you know the list of documents. My experience is that the list varies according to the person who is going to process your application. I was to bring a set of documents during blue card application and my friend was asked to bring a different set of documents. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The rules typically depend on the city/land where you live. For Berlin, the requirements for each specific type of residence permit are listed on the web site of the Ausländerbehörde, [here is an example for residence permit for a purpuse of employment](https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/dienstleistungen/service.493516.php/dienstleistung/305304/). In general, I would not worry too much, if you have everything listed there, but still asked about some extra documents. Probably in such case your application will still be taken, and you can send missing documents via post/e-mail. In the worst case, you will need to come there one more time in person, which is probably also not so critical...